# Hdmi Coupler as a cable?

Tags: hdmi, kodi

Will a HDMI coupler like the one below work like a normal HDMI cable?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yup, these are passive "pass through" devices, so the only thing you need to be careful of is matching up the genders.
The adaptor you've shown is Female-Female, so can be used to join together 2 regular HDMI cables (which are always Male-Male) to make a longer cable; but can't be plugged directly into the Raspberry Pi (which has a Female HDMI connector).